# C Program Typecasting Argv from double to a string of characters

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

I have the following assignment that I am stuck on and could use help. The part that I am stuck on is:

Command line flags should be used to determine which option to run. See man getopt_long. for details on how to do this. All floating point formats are IEEE754 unless otherwise noted. Read in a double precision floating point value from the command line, and print the following interpretations of the bit pattern:

Part 5: Read in a double precision floating point value, and print the following interpretations of the bit pattern (--print, -p):

1. A string of characters

Here is my code so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //allows exit failure
#include <getopt.h> //allows getopt_long

union double_convert {
    double to_double;
    char to_char[8];
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int c = 0;
    int option_index = 0;

   static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"print", 1, 0, 'p'},
        {"help", 0, 0, 'h'},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
    
   while ((c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:h", long_options, &option_index)) != -1) {
        switch(c) {
            case 'p':
                union double_convert input;
                sscanf(optarg, "%lf", &input.to_double);
                size = sizeof(input.to_double);
                printf("%s as a string of characters:\n", optarg);
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    printf("Value of to_char[%s]: %d\n", i, input.to_char[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 'h':
                printf("--print or -p : \n\tread a double precision floating point and print all     parts of the value\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unknown option.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    if (optind < argc) {
        printf("non-option ARGV-elements: ");
        while (optind < argc) {
            printf("%s ", argv[optind++]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
./main -p 65666768
Value of to_char[0]: 
Value of to_char[1]: 
Value of to_char[2]: 
Value of to_char[3]: 
Value of to_char[4]: D
Value of to_char[5]: C
Value of to_char[6]: B
Value of to_char[7]: A
```

**Actual output:**

```
./main -p 65666768
65666768 as a string of characters:
Value of to_char[0]: 
Value of to_char[1]: 
Value of to_char[2]: 
Value of to_char[3]: �
Value of to_char[4]: �
Value of to_char[5]: O
Value of to_char[6]: �
Value of to_char[7]: A
```

**Troubleshooting:**
When I convert it to integers, I get the following:

```
./main -p 65666768
65666768 as a string of characters:
Value of to_char[0]: 0
Value of to_char[1]: 0
Value of to_char[2]: 0
Value of to_char[3]: -128
Value of to_char[4]: -10
Value of to_char[5]: 79
Value of to_char[6]: -113
Value of to_char[7]: 65
```

**Problem statement:**
Its reading in the first value correctly, but none of the others. I've tried various things to figure it out, but am stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: A, B, C, and D is not output you would get from interpreting the IEEE-754 binary64 representation of “65666768” is a sequence of characters. If you split “65666768” into four two-digit strings and interpret them as decimal numbers, you get 65, 66, 67, and 68, and those are the ASCII codes for A, B, C, and D. That has nothing to do with floating-point. Either your assignment is stated incorrectly or there are significant parts you have omitted from the question.

Comment: The number that *would* work is 2393736.

Comment: The intent of this part of the assignment is to take a piece of memory that is 64-bits, read 2 hex bits (8 bits) and convert to a char value. This is intended to lead to the next part, which is regarding little-endian and big-endian, hence the need to read the values bit by bit. The value "65666768" is not a floating point value - you are correct. However, I used that value since it would be easier to troubleshoot than trying to figure out the ASCII equivalent of 28.5 or a different floating point value.

Comment: You're using a `union` to convert from a `double` to a character array. You can reverse that process. Put whatever you want into the character array, and then print the `double`.

Comment: Note that doesn't help you determine endianness. To prove endianness, you must take a number like 28.5 and manually compute the bytes per IEEE-754. Then you can see whether the bytes are arranged MSB first or LSB first in the array. That may be the point of the exercise: to encourage you to become familiar with IEEE-754 encoding.

Comment: @user3386109 the number "2393736" does indeed give me an output of 65, 66, 67, 68. Can you explain how you got that number? As for your comment regarding Endianness - yes you are correct. The step I am on is just a few steps before we solve for Endianness. That is why I printed the values out the way I did (value[0], value[1], value[2], etc), to display the values in the order of Endian (in this case, since the value 65 was in value[7], this shows that it follows little-endian).

Comment: I got that number by putting `0,0,0,0,68,67,66,65` into the `input.to_char` array, and then printing `input.to_double`. The `union` works both ways, converting a `double` to an array, and converting an array into a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty UBs:

```
printf("Value of to_char[%s]: %d\n", i, input.to_char[i]);
```

`i` is `int` and you try to print it as string.

Modified program showing something meaningful:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int c = 'p';
    int option_index = 0;
    size_t size;
    union double_convert input;

    
    switch(c) {
        case 'p':
            sscanf(argv[1], "%lf", &input.to_double);
            size = sizeof(input.to_double);
            for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                printf("Value of to_char[%zu]: 0x%llx\n", i, (unsigned char)input.to_char[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;
    }

    input = (union double_convert){.to_char = {0, 0, 0, 0, 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'}};
    printf("%f\n", input.to_double);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Value of to_char[0]: 0x0
Value of to_char[1]: 0x0
Value of to_char[2]: 0x0
Value of to_char[3]: 0x80
Value of to_char[4]: 0xf6
Value of to_char[5]: 0x4f
Value of to_char[6]: 0x8f
Value of to_char[7]: 0x41

2393736.000000
```

As you see to print those characters you need to enter 2393736.